# Print job submitted to printer, but didn't print anything. Java

Tags: java, service, printing

I have problem with Java print service. I need to print a simple text document, to my default printer. I use HP Deskjet as my printer on Windows machine, all driver installed. This is the source code I use:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.print.*;

public class PrintTest {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  File file = new File("print.txt");
  InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

  //Discover the default print service.
  PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

  //Doc flavor specifies the output format of the file.
  DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;  


  // Create the print job
  DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
  //Create the Doc
  Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);

  //Order to print
  try {
   job.print(doc, null);
  } catch (PrintException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }  

  is.close();
  System.out.println("Printing done....");
 }

}
```

I can see the print job on printer queue for several milisecond before its gone. But nothing get printed. I have heard it's because Java Print Service in JDK 1.6 is still buggy. But I'm not entirely sure. Any ideas why?

Comment: please let me know if you found any solution, i m facing same issue. give your response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810865/print-current-html-page-on-printer-from-java-bean-in-jsf)

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a very late answer but I had the same problem on Windows with PDFs (not text). It seems that printers may not be able to deal with native PDFs, so the job is accepted but nothing happens (no error too). I solved this by using a third-party lib, [Apache PdfBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/), and it worked like a charm.

I wrote some code example by answering a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/39271053/935039.